# Should value of equation outcome be treated as variable for Random Forest model training?

Tags: random-forest

For example, I got 5 variables, A to E, for prediction of a value.

A

B

C = A - B

D

E

the output of random forest rank C, B and A are variables with the most importance in descending order, my question is should I put (A and B) together with C into model training or they should be mutually exclusive?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If this were a linear model then they would be exclusive, you would either put A+B or C, but not both because of perfect correlation (multicollinearity problem), if C is really as simple as A-B (simple difference). The reason being that linear models consider all variables at the same time when fitting the model.

However, since you are doing a RF model the situation is different, trees consider only one variable at a time when doing splits, so if a difference in these two variables is important then you should include this difference into the model, since tress can learn this association as well but with more (in this case unnecessary) work. Whether to include both A+B and C is a different topic, it probably won't hurt a RF, so I would say do it, maybe it's not just the difference that matters but also the levels of both A and B.

Answer (score 1):

With Random Forest it is better to include as many features as possible, and then let the algorithm select which ones are most useful. Thus, include A, B, and C (even if C is a function of A and B).